# Trouble with custom font and while loops

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-face

When I try to load multiple custom fonts in while loop, only the first font is loaded. The other fonts would render as the first font. 
ex: fontList[3] would load as fontList[0] in this scenario.

```
    var fontNum = 0;
    while (fontNum < 4) {
        document.getElementById("Preloader" + fontNum).style.font = "30px " + FontList[fontNum];
        document.getElementById("Preloader" + fontNum).innerHTML = "testtext";
        fontNum++;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Could you post the rest of your code?